# How can I run a shell script safely from a multi-threaded C++ Linux application?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, fork

Here is my problem - I have a multi-threaded (pthreads) C++ application in which I have a main control loop thread, and 3 data acquisition threads (one serial port reader/writer and two TCP socket connection threads). At certain points during the program I need to execute a shell script. I have done a fair bit of research and see that `system()` is an option. Alternative options seem to indicate the use of `fork()` and the `exec()` family of functions.

The problem that I anticipate is that the use of `fork()` will result in my process being duplicated, and clearly this is going to cause me no end of problems do to my communications threads running. As `system()` documentation indicates that it uses `fork()` behind the scenes, this also means that I cannot use it.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. Is there a best practice approach to this kind of problem? The only possible way I can see to proceed is to try and create directly in C++ code the functionality of the shell script that I need to run. Obviously the man hours required to do this make it the least desirable option. Are there any other options I can look into?

Comment: You are not the first person who wants to use a `fork` in a multithreaded program...

Comment: Why not use fork in connection with one of the exec functions. Maybe even waiting for the forked process to finish execution?

Comment: @n.m. I didn't think I would be but I found surprisingly little information on it here on SO. Hence the question.

Comment: That's because it Just Works. If it didn't you *would* find lots of information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem that I anticipate is that the use of fork() will result in my process being duplicated, and clearly this is going to cause me no end of problems do to my communications threads running.

`fork()` actually only duplicates the *calling thread*.  From `man fork`:

> Note the following further points:
>
> The  child process is created with a single thread—the one that called fork().  The entire virtual
>             address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition
>             variables,  and  other  pthreads  objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing
>             with problems that this can cause.

I.e. there will not be a whole new set of duplicated worker threads wreaking havoc in the background. This is stipulated by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html). Just don't touch the mutexes, etc.  The first thing `system()` will do inside the fork is call `exec()`, so that is not a problem.  The choice between using that or doing the fork yourself depends upon whether or not you want to wait for the subprocess to complete, or just start it and keep going.

Comment: That is great and makes my life considerably simpler - thanks for your help.